# Declaring, changing, and adding to an array of a list of structs in C++

Tags: c++, list, struct, linked-list, malloc

I've created a struct and the struct has a metric on it. I am generating a series of these structs and I want to sort them into an array based on this metric. Basically, if the metric is 0, I want it in the list in the [0] slot of the array, if the metric is 14, I want it in the list in the [14] slot of the array. The bound on the metric (size of the array) is variable based on the same variable that the structs are generated off of, so I need the array to be declared dynamically with malloc. I've been experimenting with how to get this array of lists of my struct. I can't figure it out. I've googled the problem and haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Also, once I have the array, how do I add another element to the list of a particular array cell? And then go back through and compare all elements of the list in the i th cell to the elements of the (n-i)th cell?

Edit: It may also help that not all of the metrics will have elements.

Edit 2: I've tried this and it seems to have some problems.

```
list<s_pair> *pairs;
pairs = (list<s_pair>*) malloc(sizeof(list<s_pair>) * (N + 1));

j = { a, b };
pairs[m].push_back(j);
```

where m is the metric for j which is of type s_pair. It's letting me compile, but it gets stuck trying to push_back(j).

Comment: Is there only ever one struct with each metric, and is your distribution dense (aka has few or no holes)? Please be aware that `declaring` has not the meaning you use, you want `defining` or `allocating`. That is especially important for C and C++, where they are all distinct and well-defined concepts. (`defining` implies `declaring`, but not the other way around)

Comment: No. Each metric has the potential for having no structs or a bunch of structs. And I'd have to say that a quarter of the metrics may not have any structs, but the rest should have at least one.

Also, noted. What does declaring do that defining doesn't?

Comment: Looks like you are describing a hash-table with open chaining. (your metric is the hash function)

Comment: Take a look at the C standard, that defines those concepts. There are freely available drafts. Anyway, you want one for all your reference needs.

Comment: I edited the question with an update on what I tried. Can you let me know if I'm headed in the right direction? Or if this is going to be completely wrong? If it's not gonna end up working, can you link me to hash-table examples?

Comment: `(list<s_pair>*)` is a syntax error in C. Perhaps this was supposed to be a C++ question?

Comment: I can work in either C or C++. So answer as if it were C++.

Comment: In C++ it's almost certainly a mistake to `malloc` your `list`  , since this reserves space but does not construct any objects.  I'd recommend picking a language as the answer is quite different in each .

Comment: Let's go C++. I've never used 'new' before, though.

Comment: You are trying several new things at once; I *strongly* recommend tackling them one at a time. Can you get a single `list<s_pair>` to work? How about constructing two such lists, and comparing their elements? Are you sure you want to use an array? If so, can you get an array of `int` to work in C++ style? If not, how about a `vector` or a `map`?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

size_t metric(s_pair const &);   

class MyTable
{
   std::vector< std::list<s_pair> > table;

public:
    void insert(s_pair s) 
    {
         size_t index = metric(s);
         if ( index + 1 > table.size() )
              table.resize(index + 1);
         table[index].push_back(s);
    }
};
```

(obviously you'd have other functions for accessing the table and so on).

In this setup it's not going to work very well if `metric` can be a huge number (say, 2 billion). In that case you need a *sparse array* instead of a vector (C++ doesn't have a standard sparse array, but you can find one or make one).

Sample usage:

```
int main()
{
    MyTable items; 
    items.insert( whatever );
}
```

In this example, metrics with no item are represented by empty lists.

Comment: If you haven't used C++ much before, you have to make sure that `s_pair` has proper value semantics (so that if it is copied or moved, it stays as valid objects). The easiest way to do this is to make it only have member variables which have proper value semantics themselves.